# Leverage .Net to deal with 133 textBoxes?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a 19 X 7 table with a textBox in each cell. Some textBoxes need to be read only, depending on the data that is loaded into them. On saving I have to examine each textbox and see if the value needs to be saved. Having to list 133 textboxes by hand takes a long while. I would be ecstatic to get it down to a row level, so I would only need to deal with 7 textBoxes and let .Net duplicate my effort 19 times.

Is there better way to leverage .Net?

The repeater looks promising, but I don't know how to reference a control that has been repeated, more over a group of controls.

Comment: Rethink your design or what ever abomination you are attempting.

Comment: It's actually a very common scenario, so common that there is a control built specially for it.  DataGridView.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you considered a [DataGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.aspx) with DataBinding?

Answer (score 3):

The [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0ywh3cz.aspx) has been made for this

Answer (score 0):

DataList is most easily to use in this case. I Think.